# TRemotable Descendant Parent Members are not included in WSDL generated by delphi web services

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I've made Web Services with Delphi in the past but most were pretty simple that just took a few parameters and returned a single value to the client. A new service I am working on calls for me to be able to send and receive complex types. Consider the following types are defined in my code:

```
TBaseRequest = Class(TRemotable)
  private
    FUsername: string;
    FPassword: string;
  published
    Property Username: String read FUsername write FUsername;
    Property Password: String read FPassword write FPassword;
End;

TBaseResponse = Class(TRemotable)
  private
    FStatusMessage: string;
    FStatusCode: integer;
  published
    Property StatusMessage: string read FStatusMessage write FStatusMessage;
    Property StatusCode: integer read FStatusCode write FStatusCode;
End;

TSepecialRequest = class(TBaseRequest)
private
  FExtraParam: string;
published
  Property ExtraParam: String read FExtraParam write FExtraParam;
end;

TSpecialResponse = class(TBaseResponse)
private
  FExtraResult: string;
published
  Property ExtraResult: String read FExtraResultwrite FExtraResult;
end;
```

All of these classes are registerd with RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass.

Now I've also got the following function defined in the interface for this webservice:

```
function SpecialMethod(request:TSepecialRequest): TSpecialResponse;
```

In the service code I can easily access the parent class properties like Username and Password, but if we look at the WSDL that is generated we see that the TSpecialRequest and TSpecialResponse class members are included in the schema section.

```
  <xs:complexType name="TSpecialRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TBaseRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ExtraParam" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TSpecialResponse">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TBaseResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ExtraResult" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

This schema fragment in the WSDL shows that the TSpecials are extentions of the TBase classes and all is well except that the decription of the TBase classes are not included in the schema. I would expect there to also be a section like this, but it is missing:

```
  <xs:complexType name="TBaseRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TBaseResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="StatusMessage" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="StatusCode" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

However this schema fragment is missing from the generated WSDL. This means that any client attempting to use this service will not be able to correctly generate requests or interpret responses. For example, if I attempt to load the geneated WSDL into the WSDL importer in Delphi 2009, I get the following classes:

```
TSpecialRequest = class(TRemotable)
private
  FExtraParam: WideString;
published
  property ExtraParam: WideString read FExtraParam write FExtraParam;
end;

TSpecialResponse = class(TRemotable)
private
  FStatusMessage: WideString;
  FStatusCode: Integer;
published
  property StatusMessag: WideString read FStatusMessage write FStatusMessage;
  property StatusCode: Integer read FStatusCode write FStatusCode;
end;
```

The result is that the client code is unable to do things like set the username and password members that should be part of TSpecialRequest.

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening or what I can do about it?

Comment: How can I use the Delphi IDE to create a WSDL from Delphi class source code? Until now I have not seen a way to do this with Delphi 2009 Enterprise (maybe I should make it a new SO question :)

Comment: Its off-topic and should be a new question, but basically when you create a a SOAP Server Application project it will add a data module with a TWSDLHTMLPublish component on it. This component goes through registered interfaces and remotable classes and adds generates a WSDL. To access the WSDL the project's compiled DLL must be loaded into a ISAPI web server (like IIS) and then using a URL like http://server.com/project.dll you will be presented with an HTML page that describes the service and links to the generated WSDL. Result: WSDL based on classes defined in delphi code.

Comment: If the QC server is up, you can find the related bug report at http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121778 otherwise at https://web.archive.org/web/20180515072943/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121778

Comment: At my job, we had the same (or at least very similar) issue: generating from a WSDL file in Tokyo 10.2 had the same problem, whereas doing this in Rio 10.3 worked. We're not sure if different options were enabled or disabled however... Due to shortage of time we did not make it to tracking down the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I am going to get an answer but I have found a work around. I'm not really satisified with it, but It gets me passed the problem. The symptom described above can be avoided by using Object Composition instead of inheritance. This code functions as expected but it is less simple to use. I suppose I'll want to come up with some kind of message factory in my implementation but thats getting off topic.

This solution can be illustrated by the following code:

```
TBaseRequest = Class(TRemotable)
  private
    FUsername: string;
    FPassword: string;
  published
    Property Username: String read FUsername write FUsername;
    Property Password: String read FPassword write FPassword;
end;

TSepecialRequest = class(TRemotable)
private
  FExtraParam: string;
  FBaseRequest: TBaseRequest;
published
  Property ExtraParam: String read FExtraParam write FExtraParam;
  Property BaseRequest: TBaseRequest read FBaseRequest write FBaseRequest;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Delphi only generates the schema for classes that are directly referenced in the web service's interface.  Ideally it should include base classes back to TRemotable, but it doesn't.

I've found, though, if you add a dummy method to your interface with your base classes in the parameter list, Delphi will generate the missing definitions.  For example:

```
procedure BaseClasses(BaseRequest: TBaseRequest; BaseResponse: TBaseResponse); stdcall;
```

This is definitely a hack and it's a bit annoying to have to expose a method like this, but it does accomplish what you want done.

I know this response is a bit late for you but maybe it'll useful for someone else down the road.